# How to update models and migrate in Django it on LIVE environment without any downtime?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 1.8.
Whenever I make changes to models.py I have to make new migration file with `python manage.py makemigrations`.Then to reflect into DB by using `python manage.py migrate`.

Suppose I  have added a null-able field to a model Product.
Product contain more than a million record and its on live env. I know when I run `makemigrations` it will create a migration file.when I run migrate It will run `Alter Table` and it will lock Product table.

How can I add or alter field in models without downtime on live env?.
Suggest a best way.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Alter table without locking the entire table
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424543/alter-table-without-locking-the-entire-table

Comment: [Django migrations without downtime](http://pankrat.github.io/2015/django-migrations-without-downtimes/)