# Add column + index in same statement

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to add the following as one statement instead of two? Each of the following statements takes a few hours to run so I was wondering if on creation it can be indexed?

```
alter table main_table add `last_updated` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
alter table main_table add index (last_updated);
```

Comment: As far as I know the column is added to the table (file) and the index is a separate file so even if they're merged in a single command they'd probably still take the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify your MySQL server version or table engine, but if you're on InnoDB using a recent version of MySQL (> 5.6), have you considered using explicit [Online DDL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-online-ddl.html)?

```
ALTER TABLE main_table
  ADD `last_updated` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  ADD INDEX (`last_updated`),
      ALGORITHM=inplace,
      LOCK=none;
```

Note that there are [some constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html#innodb-online-ddl-summary-grid) on when the in-place algorithm can be used.

If you have foreign key constraints in effect, [disable those](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) or the copy algorithm will be used. And it'll be slow.

If your table was created pre-5.6, then you'll need to [rebuild the table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35426301/2908724) using a copy algorithm before you can switch to the inplace algorithm.

Finally, if you're using pre-5.6 or these don't work for whatever reason, consider using [Percona's online-schema-change](http://www.fromdual.com/online-ddl_vs_pt-online-schema-change).

Answer (score 3):

According to the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html), the relevant part of ALTER TABLE syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    [alter_specification [, alter_specification] ...]

alter_specification:
  | ADD [COLUMN] col_name column_definition
        [FIRST | AFTER col_name]
  | ADD {INDEX|KEY} [index_name]
        [index_type] (index_col_name,...) [index_option] ...
```

which says that you can do both adding a column and an index in the same statement.

I have tested this (on MySQL 5.6) and it works fine:

```
alter table main_table add `last_updated` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
add index (last_updated);
```